# Is there a difference between dereferencing and calling clone() and calling` to_owned in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is there any difference between the following two lines of Rust code?

```
let my_reference_type : &SomeType;

let a = my_reference_type.to_owned();
let b = (*my_reference_type).clone();
```

I realize that calling `clone()` on a reference type directly creates a clone of the reference. In other words, the returned type is also a reference, and presumably (?) references the same object referenced by the previously existing reference?

Comment: They're fundamentally different semantics, one creates a clone of something, the other takes something borrowed and makes something owned out of it.

Comment: As far as I know, `my_reference_type.clone()` will clone the reference only if the referenced type does not implement `Clone`.

Comment: Maybe the confusion comes because somewhere you have a `&String` and somewhere else a `&str`, and while `String` is `Clone`, `str` is not; while `str` does implement `ToOwned`.

Answer (score 2):

> I realize that calling clone() on a reference type directly creates a clone of the reference. In other words, the returned type is also a reference

That is not (universally) true.

You can see for yourself e.g. on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2488dd2497dd177a40aa4c8a8652d625).

```rust
fn main() {
  let a_string: String = "foo".to_string();
  
  let a_string_ref = &a_string;
  
  let a_string_owned: String = a_string_ref.to_owned();
  
  // Note my explicit type annotation. It's String, not &String
  let a_string_cloned_from_ref: String = a_string_ref.clone();
  
}
```

If you change the type in the last line from `String` to `&String` you will get a compiler error.

Here's the explanation, to the best of my knowledge, why it works the way it does.

There is some subtlety around which traits are implemented for which types, but *also* around which *methods* are implemented for which types.

Let's start with the `Clone` trait. If you implement `Clone` for a type `T`, there'll be a method `clone(&self) -> T`. Note that the argument to `clone` has type `&self`. That means implementing `Clone` for a type `T` means implementing a method `clone` for a type `&T`.

Now let's consider the two cases you bring up:

#### Calling `clone` for a `&String`

That's just stock standard method resolution: You have a type `&String` and there is a method `clone(&String)` because, and that's maybe the subtle part, `String` implements `Clone`.

Because methods that exactly match the type take "first dibs" in the method resolution, that's what you get: See [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) for an in-depth explanation.

#### Calling `clone` on `String`

You might *think* that that's the "standard path" but it's not. `String` implements `Clone`, which means there exists a method `clone(&self)`, but as you can see, the type of the argument is `&String`, not `String`.

So what next? That's where the [in-depth explanation)(https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) comes in again. If there's no method, either on the type itself or on its traits, that exactly matches the type, the compiler will also consider a bunch of other types:

- It'll deref the given type as often as possible and throw the resulting types as candidate types into a list
- For each candidate in the list, it'll then add a reference to that type and a mut ref to that type to the list
- Then it'll try until it finds a method that matches.

So in our case, after looking for a `clone` method that takes a `String`, it'll now look for a `clone` method that takes a `&String`. And that of course exists, so now we're back at the "calling clone on a reference"

### What about cloning the reference itself

In that case, following the explanation above, you'd want to call `clone` on a reference to the reference so that the order works out the way you need it to:

```rust
let cloned_reference: &String = (&a_string_ref).clone();
```

But references are `Copy` anyway so you might as well just do:

```
let copied_reference: &String = a_string_ref;
```

Comment: `&String` implements `Clone` [as do all `&T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#trait-implementations-1) but the `impl Clone for String` implementation is discovered first.

Comment: @cadolphs: I think that the `String::clone` is discovered first instead of `<&String>::clone`, not because of ergonomics, but because you are calling `.clone()` on a `&String` and `Clone::clone(&self)` takes a reference, to `Self`, so that generic resolves to `String` by default.

Comment: I don't understand your final line. It seems to be obvious to me that it shouldn't work, because you are trying to clone a reference, and store that reference into something which is not a reference. Am I missing something here? It seems like an obvious point which isn't worth stating.

Comment: But `a_string_ref.clone()` *does not* clone a reference. It clones the thing that's being referenced.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks for bringing that up. I went back to the docs to really groq what's going on here. I THINK I fixed it properly now.